# jQuery menu similar to the one on Facebook's Help Centre

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, slide

I'm building a Help Center for a website and I'd like to do something like Facebook does on their Help Centre site:

https://www.facebook.com/help

As you can see, there's a menu on the left hand side. When clicking on a section that has an arrow to the right of the menu item, the subpages for that section slide in. You can keep on clicking subpages and get their nested children. It also gives you the ability to go back to the previous parents.

I have been looking around and can't find anything like it... maybe I'm not looking for the right thing as I'm looking for things like "jQuery/Javascript sliding menu" etc etc, but most results are related to mobile menus, which is not what I'm looking for.

Anyone has come across anything similar? Just need a starting point really.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I ask why you gave me a -1 Shadow fax?

Comment: I see... misuse of the Facebook tag. Sorry! :S

Answer (score 1):

After looking and looking I decided to give it a try and write it from scratch... and I got it to work! :)

It's a bit hacky as I'm quite new to jQuery so if anyone wants to improve it feel free.

Let me know if you have any questions or ways to improve it.

Here's the jQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var content_height = jQuery(".column-right").height(); // Get height of main content
    jQuery(".subnav").height(content_height); // Apply height to menu div

    jQuery('a.forward').next().hide(); // Hide all children from the menu

    jQuery('a.forward').click(function(e) { // On click .forward
        e.preventDefault();

        // Clone next child, append to container, position absolute and animate left
        jQuery(this).next().clone(true, true).appendTo(".subnav").css({position: "absolute", left:"191px", top:"0", display:"block"}).animate({
            left:"0"
        }, 300);

        // Animate current menu out sight
        jQuery(this).closest("ul").animate({
            left:"-191px",
        }, 300);

        return false
    });

    jQuery('a.back').click(function(e) { // On click .back
        e.preventDefault();

        // Animate the previous hidden element so it comes back
        jQuery(this).closest("ul").prev().animate({
            left:"0",
        }, 300);

        // Animate current menu out of sight to the right
        // and remove after animation is completed
        jQuery(this).closest("ul").animate({
            left:"191px",
        }, 300, "linear",function(){jQuery(this).remove()});
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here's the fiddle with some CSS and HTML:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mh35b/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Modified the above post to make it more dynamic.

```js
// Code goes here

var PANEL_WIDTH = 235;
$(function() {

  $(".help-section").css("width", (PANEL_WIDTH * 2) + "px")
  $(".help-subsection, .help-question-panel, .help-left-panel").css("width", PANEL_WIDTH + "px");

  $(".help-subsection>li:not(.help-section-back)>a").click(function(e) {
    $(".help-question-panel").html($("ul", $(e.target).parent()).html());
    $(".help-question-panel").append("<li><a href='#' onclick='clickBack(event)' data-target='back'>Back</a></li>");
    $(".help-subsection").animate({
      "margin-left": "-" + PANEL_WIDTH + "px"
    }, 300);
  });
  $("a[data-target='question']").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("test");
  });

});

function clickBack(e) {
  $(".help-subsection").animate({
    "margin-left": "0px"
  }, 200, function() {
    $(".help-question-panel").html("");
  });
}
```

```css
.help-subsection {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  float: left;
}
.help-question-panel {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.help-section {
  width: 600px;
}
.help-left-panel {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.help-left-panel li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;*/
}
.help-left-panel li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
.help-question-coll {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Facebook Help Like Left Sliding Menu</h3>

  <div class="help-left-panel">
    <div class="help-section">
      <ul class="help-subsection">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
          <ul class="help-question-coll">
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">This can be a realy really long question?</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">I cannot anticipate how long this question will be! but it can be really really long.</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 1.3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 1.4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
          <ul class="help-question-coll">
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 2.1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 2.2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 2.3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 2.4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
          <ul class="help-question-coll">
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 3.1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 3.2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 3.3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="question">Question 3.4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="help-section-back">
          <a href="#">Back</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="help-question-panel">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```